# Marker Manager doesnt work in Maps API 3.10

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markermanager

Marker Manager doesn't work on Google Maps API v3.10 and in current.

If you check it's example page 
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/examples/google_northamerica_offices.html
you'll see that map is not changed by zoom control, and there is no any marker. And you will see the following JavaScript error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substr' of undefined

But if you load Maps API for version `v=3.9`, then all will be OK (I checked it on my test page).

I think there is a bug in manager's script file.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: My question is - where I should post this issue for developers to fix it, or you can do that.
It can be as a google map api "bug", or the markermanager developer have to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Marker Manager is not compatible with Google Maps API v 3.10 and above. Either specify the version when including Google Maps or change line 98 in markermanager.js (version 1.0) from

```
if (typeof map.mapTypes.get(sType) === 'object' && typeof map.mapTypes.get(sType).maxZoom === 'number') {
```

to

```
if (sType != "constructor" && typeof map.mapTypes.get(sType) === 'object' && typeof map.mapTypes.get(sType).maxZoom === 'number') {
```

Comment: Thanks Emil.
It means that I should copy markermanager.js into my project and fix it, or is there way to get version "1.1" :)

Comment: You can find the development version of version 1.1 here: http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#MarkerManager But it doesn't fix this particular problem. Unless you absolutely need a v 3.10 feature, I would go with you fix and add v=3.9 to the map include.